# Swift Sorting Array<Array<AnyObject>>

Tags: swift

I have the below response. how to sort according to the first element. i.e. `[["Albania", "AE"], ["United States", "US"]]`

```
[
  [
    "United States",
    "US"
  ],
  [
    "Albania",
    "AE"
  ]
]
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way to achieve this using [Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html).

Here is a Shorthand way of sorting.

```
    let array = [["United States","US"],["Albania", "AE"],["India", "IN"],["United Kingdom", "UK"]]
    print(array)

    let arrAscending = array.sort({($0[0]) < ($1[0])})
    let arrDescending = array.sort({($0[0]) > ($1[0])})

    print(arrAscending)
    print(arrDescending)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var array = [ [ "United States", "US" ], [ "Albania", "AE" ] ] 
array.sortInPlace({$0[0] < $1[0]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var a = [ [ "United States", "US" ], [ "Albania", "AE" ] ]

a.sort { (first, second) -> Bool in
   return first.first < second.first
}
```

Comment: This won't properly sort names that have the first or more letters in common, e.g. `Indonesia` and `India`.

Comment: Fixed according to comment.